# I need to update list adapter in background auto refresh listview and notify user if there new data from database

Tags: java, android

Hello I am creating a social network in android, I have fetching data from mysql data and put it in listview Adapter but I need auto refresh for listview and notification if there is new insert data, I am using Broadcast receiver and service but it there is nothing happen please help me
     here is my code

```
Broadcast receiver

public class BraodcastReceiverNotif extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static int noOfTimes = 0;
    JSONObject data;
    Exception exception;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;;
    public static final String mypreference = "pkAppPrefs";
    int pageNumber = 0;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
    Intent intnt;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        noOfTimes++;
        //Toast.makeText(context, "BC Service Running for " + noOfTimes + " times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        noOfTimes++;
        try {
            startNetworkCalls ();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void startNetworkCalls () throws JSONException {

        data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("user_key", sharedpreferences.getString("userKey", ""));
        data.put("city_id", sharedpreferences.getString("user_city_id", ""));
        data.put("sector_id", sharedpreferences.getString("sector_id", ""));
        data.put("page", pageNumber);

        String URL = ".............................................";
        getOnlinePosts onlinePosts = new getOnlinePosts();
        onlinePosts.execute(URL);
    }
    private class getOnlinePosts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
        private final String LOG_TAG =getOnlinePosts.class.getSimpleName();
        private Exception exception = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String docsJson = null;
            String JsonDATA = data.toString();
            String JsonResponse = null;
            Context context = null;

            try {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Started Connecting to " + params[0] + " Sending " +JsonDATA);
                url = new URL(params[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(JsonDATA);
                writer.close();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }

                docsJson = buffer.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "My data is: " + docsJson);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                exception = e;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }

            try {
                return getDocumentDataFromJson(docsJson);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // this will only happen if there is an error
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {


        }
    }
    private String[] getDocumentDataFromJson(String documentJsonStrArr)
            throws JSONException {

        final String data_status = "status";
        final String data_data = "data";
        final String data_name = "fullname";
        final String data_username = "community"; 
        JSONObject documentJson = new JSONObject(documentJsonStrArr);
        String status = documentJson.getString(data_status);

        if (status.equals("success")) {

            JSONArray docs = documentJson.getJSONArray(data_data);
            if (docs.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < docs.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject singleDoc = docs.getJSONObject(i);
                   // String success = singleDoc.getString(documentJson.getString(data_status));
                    String name = singleDoc.getString(data_name);
                    String username = singleDoc.getString(data_username);


                    intnt = new Intent(context, MyService.class);

                    // Set unsynced count in intent data
                    intnt.putExtra("success", "success");
                    intnt.putExtra("name", name);

                    // Call MyService
                    context.startService(intnt);

                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

here is my service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    int numMessages = 0;
    ArrayList<SinglePost> PostEntries = null;
    public ArrayAdapter<SinglePost> mycardAdapter;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;;
    public static final String mypreference = "pkAppPrefs";

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Community.class);

        Toast.makeText(this, intent.getStringExtra("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        PostEntries.add(new SinglePost(intent.getStringExtra("post_key"),
                intent.getStringExtra("name"),
                intent.getStringExtra("username"), intent.getStringExtra("profile_image"),intent.getStringExtra("poster_key") ,
                intent.getStringExtra("postdate"),intent.getStringExtra("message") ,intent.getStringExtra("likes")  ,
                intent.getStringExtra("liked"),intent.getStringExtra("comments") ,intent.getStringExtra("commented") ,
                Boolean.parseBoolean(intent.getStringExtra("moderate")),intent.getStringExtra("sector") ,
                intent.getStringExtra("district"),intent.getStringExtra("province") ,
                intent.getStringExtra("city"),intent.getStringExtra("country") ,intent.getStringExtra("media") ,
                Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("media_count") ),
                Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("moderate_level")) ,
                Boolean.parseBoolean( intent.getStringExtra("own_post")) ,intent.getStringExtra("online")));

        //if (Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("count_data")) < Integer.parseInt(sharedpreferences.getString("count_data", ""))){

            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
            int notifyID = 9001;
            mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Alert")
                    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            // Set pending intent
            mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
            int defaults = 0;
            defaults = defaults | android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            defaults = defaults | android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            defaults = defaults | android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
            // Set the content for Notification
            mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("success"));
            // Set autocancel
            mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            // Post a notification
            mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
       // }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


MainActivity class i am passing scheduleAlarm method to check every 10 second in database and refresh my listview

  Setup a recurring alarm every 10 seconds
    public void scheduleAlarm() {

            BroadCase Receiver Intent Object
            Intent alarmIntent = new    Intent(getContext().getApplicationContext(), BraodcastReceiverNotif.class);
            // Pending Intent Object
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext().getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            Alarm Manager Object
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            // Alarm Manager calls BroadCast for every Ten seconds (10 * 1000), BroadCase further calls service to check if new records are inserted in
            // Remote MySQL DB
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 5000, 10 * 1000, pendingIntent);

    }
```

fixed format

Comment: Nice code you have there. What's the question?

Comment: thank J.Baoby my question is: I need to update list adapter in background without refresh my listview and notify user if there new data from database

Comment: Can you edit your post and add that info to your post?

Comment: Ok @J.Baoby any idea please

Comment: "I need to update list adapter in background without refresh my listview" This sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: You mean to say, you would like to show user that new data is available?

Answer (score 0):

I really dont understand your question but I got some sense.

If I understand correctly, you want to fetch data from server, store in SQLite database and display the data in Listview

To achieve this functionality,

1. Create the Http class that gets data from the server.
2. Create IntentService to make HTTP request.
3. Once receive data from the server, insert into SQLite. And Broadcast

how you can broadcast is,
you register broadcast receiver in your activity that has the listview.
The broadcast only pass the message as the 'boolean' value that determines did data fetch from the server? If successfully fetched from the server then pass boolean true and after broadcast receive , make a local db call and fetch all changes. After that you can update the listview

Comment: I have data from remote database (mysql) and I display it in my app so a user have posting a new data into remote database and to see that new record it to swipe and refresh a listview but what i need is auto refresh a listview and  to notify other users about the new post